# program to automatically add file metadata graphically into image

Tags: image-processing

I have a series of digital photos and I want to have them professionally printed to put them up for sale.

I want to test aspects of the quality of printing, so for each image, I want to have certain metadata actually appear on the image itself. That way, when I get the prints back, I can just read the information right on the photo itself.

Specifically I want to add the filename and the resolution into the image, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in a single *long* line using [imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

To change the image in place:

```
mkdir outdir
mogrify -fill red -gravity SouthWest -pointsize 60 \
 -annotate +0+5 "%f %hx%w" -path outdir\ *.jpg
```

**Note:** Take care to have a backup of your images when using mogrify as it **overwrites in place** without any warnings or prompts.

Here is one I just did:
[image]

ImageMagick is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Very Powerful
- You can also do batch resizing at the same time on the same command line.